# Differenze tra "circa" e "quasi"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, difference, adverbs

Ci sono differenze di uso o diverse sfumature di significato tra "circa", nel senso di approssimativamente, e l'avverbio "quasi"? Ad esempio, posso dire

> - Dopo *circa* un'ora di attesa, ...
> - Dopo *quasi* un'ora di attesa, ...

ma non so se questi avverbi sono sempre interscambiabili.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

È spesso conveniente guardare l'origine latina delle parole:

- *circa* è, in latino, una forma alternativa di *circum* che, a sua volta è l'accusativo di *circus*, ciò che circonda qualcosa e, per estensione, le immediate vicinanze;
- *quasi* è “come se”.

Se dico *ho aspettato circa un'ora* sto dando una misura approssimata del tempo di attesa, senza giudizi. Se dico *ho aspettato quasi un'ora* intendo che l'attesa è stata più lunga del previsto.

L'esempio non tragga in inganno, perché *quasi* può avere anche un'accezione positiva: *ho quasi finito i compiti* (cioè mi manca poco a finirli). Non vedo la possibilità di usare *circa*.

Si può dire *quasi sempre*/*quasi tutti* ma non *circa sempre*/*circa tutti*. Un uso come

> L'aspetto del tuo nato, Iperione,
>   quivi sostenni, e vidi com'si move
>   circa e vicino a lui Maia e Dione.

nel Canto XXII del Paradiso è desueto.

Answer (score 4):

*Circa* significa *approssimativamente*, mentre *quasi* significa *non del tutto*.

Quindi una quantità *circa* uguale ad un'altra può essere di poco minore, uguale, o di poco maggiore, mentre una quantità *quasi* uguale ad un'altra è solitamente di poco minore, anche se in alcuni rari casi, se l'avvicinamento avviene dalle quantità maggiori a quelle minori, può essere di poco maggiore.

Quindi, in questo caso:

- Circa un'ora = un'ora precisa o un'ora più o meno un numero di minuti o secondi il cui massimo dipende dal contesto
- Quasi un'ora = un'ora meno un numero di minuti o secondi il cui massimo dipende dal contesto